# access html table body with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried the following two way of access html table body, b) works, a) doesn't
Who can tell me why?

a)

```
var requestTableBody = $('#requestTable > tbody');

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    requestTableBody.append("<tr ><td>vvv</td></tr>");
}
```

b)

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    $('#requestTable > tbody').append("<tr ><td>vvv</td></tr>");
```

Note: the script above is a extract, like the x is actually defined. My point is that what is the diff between 
     var requestTableBody = $('#requestTable > tbody');
and access it directly?

Comment: What does your HTML `<table>` look like?

Comment: you have the error in append, get rid of the extra "

Comment: simple syntax error `""` to `"`

Comment: `b) works` so thats a typo guys .

Answer (score 0):

X isn't defined. Just replace `i < x.length` by then number of row you want to append.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyWdZ/)